# How to open an email file in a Cordova app?

Tags: ios, cordova, email, cordova-plugins, fileopener2

I would like to download email files into the `cordova.file.cacheDirectory` and open them in the default email app. I am using the [Cordova File Transfer Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html) for the download and the [File Opener Plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) to open in the default app. The download part is working fine, however the File Opener plugin is giving the following error:

> Error status: 9 - Error message: Could not handle UTI

The file I am trying to open is MIME formatted (.eml extension) and I am using the MIME type of `message/rfc822`:

```
function openFileWithDefaultApp(fileEntry) {
    var fileUrl = fileEntry.toURL();
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        fileUrl,
        'message/rfc822', {
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(
                    'Error status: ' + e.status +
                    ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log('file opened successfully');
            }
        }
    );
}
```

What am I missing?

P.S. This code is working perfectly with PDF files. Simply switching to email files is causing this issue. I am wondering if there is a "default app" for .eml files or do I have to switch some other format? One possibility is to convert emails to PDF, but that would loose attachments. Hence this is not preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to open .eml on iOS (see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3709613?start=0&tstart=0) without a specific app (eg Klammer or 'EML Viewer').

An alternative is to convert the .EML to a .PDF on a server, for which there are probably OS options (such as https://github.com/nickrussler/eml-to-pdf-converter).

Comment: Thanks, Jim. This is very useful. I finally found an app that can open .eml and .msg files - [Msg Viewer Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/msg-viewer-pro/id1019539949?mt=12). It opens .eml files from Dropbox etc using a tray interface. Unfortunately, it is not triggered from File Opener 2 - I think because it is not using the tray to open the app. File Opener 2 tries to get a UTI based on file extension or MIME type, both of which return a UTI of "com.apple.mail.email". This unfortunately does not trigger Msg Viewer Pro.